# what is the antonym of "DELETED"

Tags: antonyms

Hello what would you propose to use as opposite(antonym) word for "DELETED"?
I was thinking of "ACTIVE"

Comment: Are you talking about a state or an action?

Comment: Yes, Im talking about state.

Comment: Depends on the noun, I think. A file that is not deleted is present or existing.

Comment: *Undeleted* isn't in all dictionaries but it's clear what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Present**

> 1:  now existing or in progress 
> 2a:  being in view or at hand 
>    b: existing in something mentioned or under consideration